# Modal and anchor tag href bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 4 (I also tried using the bootstrap 3) and I think I have a buggy modal because when I add something in anchor tag href it causes it to break down like having its content changed same with my main page or it just shows and disappeared. Here's my modal and my anchor tag looks(my modal is in my packages.php while the anchor tag is inside a function which is in packageclass.php):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

packageclass.php

```
    public function GetAllData($getTbl){
    try{
        $query = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblpackages P JOIN tblpackageincluded I ON P.PackageID = I.PackageID JOIN tblrates R ON P.PackageID = R.PackageID");
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                if($getTbl == 1){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackageID'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='DeletePackages.php?id=". $row['PackageID'] ."'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='EditPackages.php?id=". $row['PackageID'] ."'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a></td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackageName'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackageCost'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackNote'] ."</td>";
                    echo '<td> <a href="?id='. $row['PackageID'] .'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>';
                    echo '<td> <a href="?id='. $row['PackageID'] .'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                else if($getTbl == 2){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackageIncID'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['PackIncluded'] ."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                else if($getTbl == 3){
                    echo "<td>". $row['RateID'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['RateCount'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $row['CostPerHead'] ."</td>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thankyou

Image of the modal after 1 second it looks like this
[image: Modal After a second]

Comment: why cant you insert an empty href, already you are using data-target, so anyway modal will popup. is that $row['PackageID'] needed in href ?

Comment: Techincally, the popup content is part of the same page, so reloading the page removes all its previous content, including popup. If you want to reload only the inner part of the popup, consider loading the content via AJAX.

Comment: Sorry my first time posting a question and really hard to format a code and I forgot to edit it properly. It's not empty I edit it for you to see that I will be using get method soon. That's why I need the href

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn So i will be needing ajax so I can use get method with modal? I'm kinda new and thankyou for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict:

1. `<a>` tags cause a postback.
2. Modals appear immediately on click driven by js

You have set up the anchor to both display the modal and then postback to retrieve the data which probably has the effect of

- closing the original modal,
- retrieving the data,
- then building a new `modal-body` table
- which won't get displayed until you click the anchor...which starts the process over again.

---

#### What to do?

You need to remove the conflict. You can...

1. Postback and retrieve the data, populate the modal-body, then auto display the modal via js on document ready. -OR-
2. On Client side click retrieve the data via ajax and populate a dynamic table during the modal show event.

If you use the postback option you can do everything as you are now with PHP.  You need to remove the modal display from anchor tag and trigger it in the jquery ready function or whatever ready method you prefer.  This is not a very clean way to do it but it is an option.

If you choose the Client side option, you may want to consider a third party dynamic table add-in.  This, in my opinion, is the better option for use with a Bootstrap modal.

Comment: so you mean that I can't use a tag with href and modal? any suggestion?

Comment: I'll make an edit with suggestions.  It's too long to place in a comment